# react navigation How to pass params or props to Tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do we pass props or params to a tab navigation component. So for I tried the follow but no luck

I am trying to send the param or prop to the component HomeTab

```
<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTab} MyParam='custom message' />
    <Tab.Screen name="Video" component={VideoTab} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: maybe this could  help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439210/how-to-pass-props-to-screen-component-with-a-tab-navigator

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={()=> <HomeTab MyParam='custom message'/>} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Video" component={VideoTab} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Here is another way using context API: [How to pass props to Screen component with a tab navigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530672/5669120)

Comment: Works but introduced a new issue. Looks like you're passing an inline function for component prop for the screen. may cause state lose on re-rendering and cause perf issues

Comment: I know it's not a right approach ,that's why I also provided one workaround using Contex API in a link given.